# PYQT5 Getting text from the Window title?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, mdi

I hope I have a simple question. I have a `pyqt mainwindow` that has an `mdi` area for sub-windows. I would like to be able to get the text of the title from a current sub-window and set it to a variable.

The reason I am doing this is that when you click on other sections of my main window I have `mdi` sub-windows that open up to edit the data that has been entered. I would like the user to be able to open and edit multiple sets of data at once and I am setting the directory key for the data in the title bar. I thought it would be a good way to differentiate between which set of data is being edited at the current moment.

I'm not sure if this is the best way or even a good way to achieve what I would like. If there is another method that would be better I would love to hear it.

Thank you for all your time.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I found the [`QMdiArea::subWindowActivated()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#subWindowActivated) in the Qt C++ doc. The [`MDISubWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html) is directly derived from [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) which in turn has a property [`windowTitle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop). I didn't try it in code but, for me, it sounds like a plan...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`QMdiArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html) provides a method [`QMdiArea::activeSubWindow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#activeSubWindow) as well as a signal [`QMdiArea::subWindowActivated()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#subWindowActivated).

The [`QMdiSubWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html) is (directly) derived from [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) which in turn provides a property [`QWidget::windowTitle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop).

Putting this altogether, it should work.

I prepared an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as "proof of concept" (and to train my Python/PyQt skills).

Sample code `testQMDIActiveSubWindow.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow

def updateActiveChild(subWindow):
  win.setWindowTitle("MDI Test: '%s'" % subWindow.windowTitle())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  # build GUI
  win = QMainWindow()
  win.resize(640, 480)
  mdiArea = QMdiArea()
  for title in ["Data:1", "Data:2", "Data:3", "Data:n"]:
    mdiChild = QMdiSubWindow()
    mdiChild.setWindowTitle(title)
    mdiArea.addSubWindow(mdiChild)
  mdiArea.tileSubWindows()
  win.setCentralWidget(mdiArea)
  win.show()
  updateActiveChild(mdiArea.activeSubWindow())
  # install signal handlers
  mdiArea.subWindowActivated.connect(updateActiveChild)
  # exec. application
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tested it in python3, cygwin64, Windows 10 (64 bit):

[image: snapshot sequence of testQMDIActiveSubWindow.py in action]

The title of active sub-window is reflected in the title of the main window.